# Is it possible to turn a MCPE world into a media fire link

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

If you don’t know there is a YouTuber called TheBowTieMan and he is doing a Bedrock Minecraft redstone thing and you have to make a redstone creation then send the world to him via mediafire through the comments. Is it possible to turn a MCPE world into a mediafire link and if it is possible, how?

Answer (score 1):

Make a MediaFire account, then edit your world in the main menu, scroll down, and click the "Export World" button. Find the `.mcworld` file, then upload it to MediaFire.

Comment: Did you know `.mcworld` files are just `.zip` files in disguise? If you rename the `.mcworld` to be a `.zip`, you can see that!

Comment: Note that the "Export World" button only appears in **Windows 10** version of Bedrock Edition. There are other ways you can get to the world on iOS.